# RethinkDB: effectively selecting by id not present in another table

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb

Given two tables:

- t1: a table with elements, and
- t2: another table with list of IDs processed from t1

How do you query for all the elements in t1, which were not yet processed, that is, does not have a corresponding pid in t2?

For clarity, I'm looking for the functional equalent of

`Select * from t1 where t1.id not in (select pid from t2)`

Alternatively, a way to implement a simple processing queue to determine which new elements in t1 have not been processed yet.

Update:

Currently I'm at the following:

`r.db("mydb").table("t1").filter( function(u) { return r.db("mydb").table("t2")("pid").contains( u("id") ).not(); })`

However, this is horribly inefficient: specifically, it requires full tablescans for every element in t2 against t1. Are there any ways to return this more efficiently?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by creating a secondary index on `t2` for `pid`:

```
r.table('t2').indexCreate('pid')
r.table('t1').filter(function(u) {
  return r.table('t2').getAll(u('id'), {index: 'pid'}).isEmpty();
})
```